# Restoring a table row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I'm working on some simple tables in SQL Server 2017, and was testing certain functionalities such as inserting/deleting table rows.

However, let's say I have deleted a table row, how would I restore it?

An example I made up is

```
create table employee_tbl
(
    Emp_Id int primary key,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Salary float,
    MobileNo varchar(15)
)

insert into employee_tbl 
values (1, 'rajon', 'rondo', 50000, '76677676653')

select *
from employee_tbl

delete from employee_tbl 
where EmpId = 1
```

Currently I understand how to insert and delete the table rows, but after deleting a table row is there a way to restore it?

Comment: See this thread [How to undo Drop Table Statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38872/how-to-undo-drop-table-statement)

Comment: That seems to provide third party application to fix the deleted row, i was looking more towards like a command or something in the actual sql server

Comment: There may be tricks to try to undelete data. However, there isn't a follproof way of doing this. If you need earlier versions of the table, restore a backup.

Comment: @Kayenine no there are no command like that, and that's why there are `restore` or `backup` process..

Comment: if the purpose is not to affect the tables during testing / debugging, enclosed the entire statement in `begin tran` and `rollback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testing certain functionalities such as inserting/deleting table rows.`

What I normally do is enclosed the statements in `BEGIN TRAN` and `ROLLBACK`.

example :

```
BEGIN TRAN

 insert into employee_tbl values (1,'rajon','rondo',50000,'76677676653')
 select *from employee_tbl

 delete from employee_tbl where EmpId=1
 select *from employee_tbl

ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances no, once you delete a row it is gone, unless you make a copy of the row. As dwir182 posted, in that link it tells you that it will overwrite it soon after it is deleted.